# php error on server when trying to post a form into xml to a file Warning: DOMDocument::save(data.xml): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, xml

I'm new into php and web html, css etc.. (2 months) self learning and I have form which I parse the values into an xml file. It works fine on my localhost but not in webhost . Apparently I have a permission issue and I don't know how to solve it.
Can someone please help but please be conscious that I'm a beginner and need detail help as I'm not familiar with this

php v 5.5.11

htaccess i've added as suggested but still don't work.

```
php_flag "allow_url_fopen" "On"
php_flag "allow_url_include" "On"
php_flag short_open_tag "On"
```

the error is:

> Warning: DOMDocument::save(data.xml): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied in
>   /home/www/1fe720ae68582bc8524d72e4d0afafcb/web/index.php on line 46
>   oupppps error on saving the page -Ask Kamran and he would NOT know
>   what to do

my code on line 46 is:

```
> $doc->save($file) or die("oupppps error on saving the page -Ask Kamran
> and he would NOT know what to do");
```

the full php code (not include html) is as follow:

```
 <?php       


$today = date("Y-m-d"); 



if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $file = "data.xml";
     $userNode ='Course';

     $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
     $doc->preserveWhiteSpace=false;
     $doc->load($file);
     $doc->formatOutput = true;

     $root = $doc->documentElement;

     $post = $_POST;
     unset($post['submit']);

     $user = $doc->createElement($userNode);
     $user = $root->appendChild($user);

     foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
          $node=$doc->createElement($key,$value);
          $user->appendChild($node);
     }
    $doc->save($file) or die("oupppps error on saving the page -Ask Kamran and he would NOT know what to do");
     header('Location:data.xml');
}

 // separation start here 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // remove submit from array for both keys and values
    $post = $_POST;
    unset($post['submit']);

    // get values
    $data = array_values($post);

    // keys are headers 
    $headers = array_keys($post);

    // open file 
    if( $fp = fopen('data.csv','a+')) {

        // get first line
        $line = fgets($fp);

        if(!$line == $headers) {    //if first line is not the same as the headers, add headers

                fputcsv($fp, $headers);
                fputcsv($fp, $data);
        }
        else
        {                           // otherwise, just add data
            fputcsv($fp, $data);
        }

        // close file
        fclose($fp);

        // redirect to thank you page
        header('Location: thanks.php'); 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to give write privileges

Comment: You are trying to create a `data.xml` file, and most probably, apache doesn't have write permissions on that directory. If you've shell access, ssh onto the server, and then use `chown` to grant permissions.

Comment: Thank you hjpotter82 for your answer but please how do I do that specifically as I have no idea how to shell access etc...   I'am so new into this apology so thank you if you can help more much appreciated.